# Single Positional Indexer is out-of-bounds with a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

I'm currently working on a conversational AI. I'm pretty new to python so a lot of what I'm doin I find on the internet, same goes with debugging. I've tried finding alternatives and debugging the error I keep getting but to no avail. The code works for everything except the Question:Regresponse

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import random 


# Load the data from the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("conversational_english.csv")

# Split the data into training and testing sets
training_data = data[:int(0.8 * len(data))]
testing_data = data[int(0.8 * len(data)):]

# Convert the text into numerical feature vectors using CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
text_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(training_data['text'])

# Train a Naive Bayes classifier on the training data
classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(text_features, training_data['label'])

# Continuously get user input and generate a response based on the label
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a conversational text: ")
    if user_input == "exit":
        break
    user_input_features = vectorizer.transform([user_input])
    predicted_label = classifier.predict(user_input_features)[0]
    if predicted_label == 'feeling_question':
        predicted_label = 'feeling_response'
    if predicted_label == 'question':
        predicted_label = 'regresponse'
    if predicted_label == 'joke_request':
        predicted_label = 'joke'
    print(predicted_label)
    response = data.loc[data['label'] == predicted_label, 'text'].iloc[0]
    print("Response:", response)
    correct = input("Is this response correct? (yes/no): ")
    if correct == "no":
        new_label = input("Enter the correct label for the user input: ")
        if user_input in data['text'].values:
            continue
        else:
            new_data = pd.DataFrame({'text': [user_input], 'label': [new_label]})
            data = data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)
            data.to_csv("conversational_english.csv", index=False)
    else: 
        if user_input in data['text'].values:
            continue
        else:
            new_data = pd.DataFrame({'text': [user_input], 'label': [predicted_label]})
            data = data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)
            data.to_csv("conversational_english.csv", index=False)
```

The CSV:

```
text,label,
Can you tell me a joke?,joke_request,
I'm not sure because I am an AI, regresponse,
Hi how are you doing today?,greeting,
Why did the chicken cross the road?,joke,
Where is the bus stop?,question,
how are you?,feeling_question,
What are you doing?,feeling_question,
I am an AI. How should I know?, regresponse,
How are you?,feeling_question,
Goodbye,farewell,
Bye,farewell,
"Two whales walk into a bar. One says ""oOooOoooOOh"". The other says ""What the hell Jim""",joke,
Hi!,greeting,
I'm not sure. I am an AI, regresponse,
Hello!,greeting,
Greetings!,greeting,
what's up?,question,
I'm doing good!,feeling_response,
What's up?,question,
Tell me a joke,joke_request,
Tell me something funny,joke_request,
I'm doing great!,feeling_reponse,
I am an AI. I don't know., regresponse,
Not bad!,feeling_response,
Hi,greeting,
Hello,greeting,
how's it going?,question,
My name is Zach,name,
how's it goin,question,
what are you up to?,question,
I don't know I am and AI, regresponse,
How are you,feeling_question,
How's it goin,question,
How do you do,feeling_question,
"A horse walks into a bar and the bartender says ""why the long face""",joke,
goodbye,farewell,
hello,greeting,
Good evening,greeting,
I'm not sure., regresponse,
hello!,greeting,
What's up,question,
Heyo,greeting,
hi,greeting,
I am an AI. I can't help you., regresponse,
How's it going?,question,
I don't know because I am an AI., regresponse,
What's up!,question,
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyn\OneDrive\Documents\test-rep\Python AI\response.py", line 35, in <module>
    response = data.loc[data['label'] == predicted_label, 'text'].iloc[0]
  File "C:\Users\Kyn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1073, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Kyn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1625, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\Kyn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1557, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
```

So far nothing has worked to fix the question:regresponse but like I said before, everything else works.

Comment: I think you have a extra space before regresponse in your csv,  ' regresponse' != 'regresponse' so data.loc[data['label'] == predicted_label, 'text'] will have a length of 0, resulting in out of bounds error.

Comment: Your code work perfectly for me.

Comment: Yashar you were correct. Thanks for the help. I'm new here, is there a way to close out the question?